# Return a column value only once in row 1 and return NULL for other rows

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, sql-order-by

```
select col1, col2, col3 from table where *some condition*
```

Here, the number of rows returned is indefinite but the value for col2 will be same.  I want to display col2 value in first row only and display as NULL in other rows.

How can I do this without complicating the query too much?

Comment: This sounds like a presentation layer effort, not one for the query.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `row_number()`, but there is no need for a subquery:

```
select
    col1,
    case when row_number() over(partition by col2 order by col1, col3) = 1 then col2 end col2
    col3
from mytable t
where ...
order by t.col2, col1, col3
```

Note that for this to work (and for your question to make sense at all), you do need some kind of ordering rule in the result set, so it can unambiguously be told with row is the *first*. I assumed that you want to order rows using the two other columns (and I also ordered the resultset accordingly).

Also please note that this solution should work equally well if there is more than one distinct `col2` in the resultset; results will be sorted, and only the first occurence of a given `col2` value will be displayed.

Comment: Thank you for the response. Using row_number solved my problem.

Comment: @JagathUthappa: welcome. Is there any reason why you accepted the solution that uses a subquery? As I explained in my answer, there is no need for a subquery and it will be more efficient without it.

Comment: Initially I had looked at the first one and it worked but later saw this response. I have implemented using your method as using subqeury is not needed.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `row_number()` :

```
select t.col2, (case when t.seq = 1 then t.col2 end) as col2, t.col3
from (select t.col1, t.col2, t.col3,
             row_number() over (partition by t.col2 order by ?) as seq
      from t
      where . . . 
     ) t;
```

Comment: Thank you for the response. Using row_number solved my problem.